# Eclipse Kura WEB UI not showing up

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, kura

I was following the [Eclipse Kura Getting Started tutorial](http://eclipse.github.io/kura/doc/configurable_component.html) to run an OSGI application and find my service under Kura Web GUI "services". While I run the bundle using Kura_Emulator_Linux, there are no errors displayed in the console log, but the Web UI did not show up in the browser by entering the URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/

[image]

Could anyone help me to point out the problem here?

```
osgi> ss
"Framework is launched."


id  State       Bundle
0   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.v20120830-144521
1   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud_1.0.2
2   ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.io_2.4.0
3   ACTIVE      org.hsqldb.hsqldb_2.3.0
4   ACTIVE      com.gwt.user_0.2.0
**5 ACTIVE      com.help.iot.example.configurable_1.0.0.qualifier**
6   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.deployment.agent_1.0.1
7   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.400.v20120522-2049
8   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.configuration_1.0.1
9   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.0.v20120522-1841
10  ACTIVE      org.json_1.0.0.v201011060100
11  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.net_1.0.2
12  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3_1.0.1
13  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0.v201110170705
14  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522
15  RESOLVED    slf4j.log4j12_1.6.0
                Master=32
16  ACTIVE      javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201112011016
17  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.util_8.1.3.v20120522
18  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.emulator_1.0.2.qualifier
19  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.deploymentadmin_0.9.5
20  ACTIVE      log4j_1.2.17
                Fragments=37
21  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522
22  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.0.v20120522-1841
23  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core_1.0.2
24  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.cm_1.0.400.v20120522-1841
25  ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.fileupload_1.2.2.v20111214-1400
26  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.soda.dk.comm_1.2.1
27  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.metatype_1.2.0.v20120522-1841
28  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.dependencymanager_3.0.0
29  ACTIVE      javax.usb.common_1.0.2
30  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.http_8.1.3.v20120522
31  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.100.v20120522-1822
32  ACTIVE      slf4j.api_1.6.4
                Fragments=15
33  ACTIVE      com.hp.iot.example.hello_osgi_1.0.0.qualifier
34  ACTIVE      javax.usb.api_1.0.2
35  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.2.200.v20120522-2049
36  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.continuation_8.1.3.v20120522
37  RESOLVED    log4j.apache-log4j-extras_1.1.0
                Master=20
38  ACTIVE      com.google.protobuf_2.6.0
39  ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.net_3.1.0.v201205071737
40  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20120522-1841
41  ACTIVE      osgi.cmpn_4.3.0.201111022214
42  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.io_8.1.3.v20120522
43  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522
44  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.300.v20120522-1841
45  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.crypto_1.0.1
46  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.util_3.2.300.v20120522-1822
47  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0.v201108120515
48  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.io_1.0.400.v20120522-2049
49  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.api_1.0.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem... The answer was I downloaded the wrong package.
There are 2 Developers Workspaces for download. On the left side without the WebUI.
Try to download the Developers Workspace on the right side (Extended Downloads) [Developers Workspace (With Web UI)](https://s3.amazonaws.com/kura_downloads/user_workspace/release/1.1.2/user_workspace_archive_1.1.2.zip) https://www.eclipse.org/kura/downloads.php

Comment: Thanks a lot. I downloaded the workspace with WebUI and it worked perfectly as per the "Getting Started" guide.